# GWT Using Yahoo to get the Weather using rss / xml

Tags: gwt

I am trying to get the data from the yahoo rss but i get a 404 (not found) and I think it is because it can not find this

http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0

does anyone know if there is a new one I whould point to? or if something has changed or I am suppose to change?.

Thank you (Code below)

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
import org.dom4j.Node;
import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;
import org.jaxen.JaxenException;
import org.jaxen.XPath;
import org.jaxen.dom4j.Dom4jXPath;

import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;
import com.packtpub.gwtbook.widgets.client.Weather;
import com.packtpub.gwtbook.widgets.client.WeatherService;

public class WeatherServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        WeatherService {

    public Weather getWeather(String zipCode) {
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        Weather weather = new Weather();
        Document document;
        try {
            document = reader.read(new URL(
                    "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=" + zipCode));

            XPath expression = new Dom4jXPath("/rss/channel");

            expression.addNamespace("yweather",
                    "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");
            expression.addNamespace("geo",
                    "http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#");

            Node result = (Node) expression.selectSingleNode(document);
            String error = result.valueOf("/rss/channel/description");
            if (error.equals("Yahoo! Weather Error")) {
                weather
                        .setError("Invalid zipcode "
                                + zipCode
                                + " provided. No weather information available for this location.");
                return weather;
            }

            String descriptionSection = result
                    .valueOf("/rss/channel/item/description");
            weather.setImageUrl(descriptionSection.substring(descriptionSection
                    .indexOf("src=") + 5,
                    descriptionSection.indexOf(".gif") + 4));
            weather.setCity(result.valueOf("//yweather:location/@city"));
            weather.setState(result.valueOf("//yweather:location/@region"));

            weather.setChill(result.valueOf("//yweather:wind/@chill"));
            weather.setDirection(result.valueOf("//yweather:wind/@direction"));
            weather.setSpeed(result.valueOf("//yweather:wind/@speed"));

            weather.setHumidity(result
                    .valueOf("//yweather:atmosphere/@humidity"));
            weather.setVisibility(result
                    .valueOf("//yweather:atmosphere/@visibility"));
            weather.setPressure(result
                    .valueOf("//yweather:atmosphere/@pressure"));
            weather.setRising(result.valueOf("//yweather:atmosphere/@rising"));

            weather.setSunrise(result.valueOf("//yweather:astronomy/@sunrise"));
            weather.setSunset(result.valueOf("//yweather:astronomy/@sunset"));

            weather.setCurrentCondition(result
                    .valueOf("//yweather:condition/@text"));
            weather
                    .setCurrentTemp(result
                            .valueOf("//yweather:condition/@temp"));

            weather.setLatitude(result.valueOf("//geo:lat"));
            weather.setLongitude(result.valueOf("//geo:long"));

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JaxenException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return weather;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but this maybe?

http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=%s'%20WEATHER_NS%20=%20'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0'